# How can I save R images generated using putty (linux server) in Xming view?

Tags: linux, r, putty, xming

I am running several codes using our server and create image using R using putty (linux server) in Xming view .I wonder how can I save my images as pdf?

Comment: There is a pdf device: `?pdf`

Comment: You have to close the device after plotting, e.g.: `pdf("foo.pdf"); plot(1:10); dev.off()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd close R, delete the blank pdf and then retry with:

```
pdf("mygraph.pdf")
plot(x)
dev.off()
```

Using putty and xming shouldn't effect anything.  Or you could try saving it as another format (to check if its an issue with your R device).

```
pdf("mygraph.pdf") #pdf file
win.metafile("mygraph.wmf")  #windows metafile
png("mygraph.png") #png file
jpeg("mygraph.jpg") #jpeg file
bmp("mygraph.bmp") #bmp file
postscript("mygraph.ps") #postscript file
```

Comment: Also are you sure you have a pdf reader on the remote machine?  Not sure how xming will react if you attempt to open a pdf and lack a reader.  Might just populate a blank window and not a blank document